# how to change android button background twice?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

1. I want to change button background from red to orange and finally to green.
2. so far I could change to orange.
3. but the background cannot change to green.
4. here the code

   ```
   Button change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_change);
   change.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_red);

   ...

   change.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_orange);
           try {
               Thread.sleep(5000, 0);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_green);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: You are actually putting your UI thread to sleep for 5s. Brilliant. Remove that and replace it with a handler.postDelayed ASAP. Make sure that button_green is not a copy paste mistake from button_orange

Comment: I second using a Handler and never putting UI thread to sleep.

Comment: I third using a handler

Comment: no need for a handler. `View.postDelayed` is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very bad practice to use `Thread.sleep()` in Android, especially on the Main UI Thread. Use timer or post runnables instead (see below).

```
change.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_orange);
        Handler handle = new Handler(); // Probably shouldn't create one each time, but here is the idea
        handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_green);
            }
        }, 5000);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Just an addendum; this is not great practice as that view is not guaranteed to be the current view when the message gets delivered.

I suggest that Data Binding or another mechanism is used to update the UI after an arbitrary time. The above answer addresses the question directly but should not be done to accomplish UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an [Animation Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html).

In your case, you'd define your drawable something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:duration="0" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/orange" android:duration="5000" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:duration="0" />
</animation-list>
```

This says, "start red then when it starts to play, immediately switch to orange for 5 seconds, then switch to green."

So in your code:

```
Button change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_change);
// This starts you off red
change.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color_animation);

...

change.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable) v.getBackground();
        // Start the animation, which will switch to orange immediately for 5 seconds, then turn green
        ad.start();
    }
});
```